# How to make an image appear in a div in Gravity Forms by selecting options?

Tags: php, jquery, gravity-forms-plugin

I'm trying to figure out how to make an images stack on one another based on options chosen using radio buttons in Gravity Forms. I have been searching for a week now and can't find any way to make this happen.

Here's an example of what I would like to achieve using Gravity Forms:
https://www.woocommerceproductconfigurator.com/configurator/configure/312

I read online that this is possible to do in HTML/CSS with the help of jQuery.

Does anyone know if this is possible to do in Gravity Forms and how I would go about getting started?

Comment: Use absolute positioning in your css to put the images in the same place (ie on top of one another), then bind an event listener to your radio buttons and show/hide the images in response to the radio button being clicked